# Inserting a function to a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie to VBA, and I try to Insert a `VLOOKUP` function.

I get the data from a webpage and after some autofiltering and auto-deleting, data shrinks to a smaller size. But since it is a dynamic data, the last row always changes.

My data is like this:

```
A          B       C
FleetType  MSN     Registration
```

I have the registration (`C`) filled up, and want to find the fleet type which is listed in a different sheet.

I tried inserting a formula by using `FormulaR1C1`, but eventually get a 1004 message. I also tried to use `Application.VLookup`, also get the 1004 message.

Since I could not make this work, as I know the first two letters of the registration gives a clue about the fleet type, I have setted up a nested `IF` function and tried to insert it; without luck also.

This is the `sub` Im trying to make it run (I have not deleted the ones that I tried):

```
Sub formuller()

    Worksheets("Data").Select
    Worksheets("Data").Activate

    'range("A1:A600").Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JK";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JG";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JF";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JH";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JV";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JJ";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="JY";"Boeing";IF(LEFT(D2;2)="LJ";"Boeing";"Airbus"))))))))"
    On Error Resume Next

    Range("A1:A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JK"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JG"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JF"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JH"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JV"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JJ"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""JY"";""Boeing"";IF(LEFT(RC[3];2)=""LJ"";""Boeing"";""Airbus""))))))))"

    On Error GoTo 0

   'Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A600").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[3];Filo!R1C1:R309C3;3;FALSE)"
```

Is there any way around this? All I am asking is for a way around just using the good old `VLookup` in a VBA project.

Comment: Change `;` to `,` and see if it works. `FormulaR1C1` uses comma as formula field separator, no matter what your local formula separator is.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` for good old `VLookup`.
But alternativly you can use this macro for your porpuse. Explanation is in comments.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindFleetType()
    Const Boeing As String = "Boeing"
    Const Airbus As String = "Airbus"
    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim MyRange, c As Range
    Dim MyInt, LastRow As Integer
    Dim MyStr, MyArray(7) As String

    'filling string array
        MyArray(0) = "JK"
        MyArray(1) = "JG"
        MyArray(2) = "JF"
        MyArray(3) = "JH"
        MyArray(4) = "JV"
        MyArray(5) = "JJ"
        MyArray(6) = "JY"
        MyArray(7) = "LJ"

    'defining worksheet
    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    'finding lastrow has data on columnn C
    'so you don't have to change the range manually every time
    With MySheet
        LastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'defining range to be filled
    Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    'iterating each cell on defined range
        For Each c In MyRange
            MyStr = Left(c.Offset(0, 2).Value2, 2) 'get first two letters of "Registration" column C
                'control if your array contains your string
                If ContainString(MyStr, MyArray) Then
                    c.Value2 = Boeing
                    Else
                    c.Value2 = Airbus
                End If
        Next
End Sub
Private Function ContainString(ByVal StringToBeFound As String, StringArray As Variant) As Boolean
  ContainString = (UBound(Filter(StringArray, StringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```